# Export RocksDB state snapshot data to hive

Tags: apache-flink

I am new to Flink and just started writing a Flink based project. My Flink job uses RocksDB as state store and the checkpoint is turned on to take a snapshot of state store to S3 every 15 minutes.

I need to query data of state store from Hive for some data analysis and found that the state data from checkpoint on S3 cannot be consumed from Hive. Is there any way to export all data from RocksDB to S3 as parquet file so that I can query them from Hive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can extract data from a Flink savepoint (and from some checkpoints, but working with checkpoints is not guaranteed) by using Flink's [State Processor API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/libs/state_processor_api.html).

For an example, see https://github.com/ververica/flink-training/blob/master/state-processor/src/main/java/com/ververica/flink/training/exercises/ReadRidesAndFaresSnapshot.java.

It might be more straightforward to have your job [stream directly to Hive](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connectors/hive/hive_read_write.html#writing).